# cp: cannot create regular file ‘Users/James/Desktop’: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm trying to copy a file from a remote server to my desktop and i'm getting the above error. I've SSH'd to the server.

Here is what i'm doing:

```
deploy@ip-10-91-135-76 /data/project/current/lib/data $ scp customer_record.ods /Users/James/Desktop
```

I have very limited experience and don't understand what is going on?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man scp` tells you how to use `scp`.  In particular, most usages look like:

```
scp [user1@]host1:]file1 [[user2@]host2:]file2
```

You can omit putting the user in if its the same as your current user, and likewise for the host.  Since you've SSH'd onto the server already, the start of your command is okay to be `scp customer_records.ods`, but the next argument has to include the user name and host of the target machine that you want to copy the file to, namely your home computer.  Chances are you actually want to go the other way, since your home computer may not have a publicly accessible IP.

1. End the SSH session, go back to your home machine.
2. Do:

   ```
   scp <user-you-sshd-as>@<server-you-sshd-to>:/data/project/current/lib/data/customer_records.ods /Users/James/Desktop
   ```

If you need to specify a private key, you can use the `-i` option: `scp -i <path-to-key> ...`